# だ without と as だと

Tags: particles, quotes

> A: やっぱり分かりませんでした
>
> B: やっぱり分かりませんだ？

B is obviously quoting A and I would expect だと here but と is not used in this utterance. I wonder if this is dialectal.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15498/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm It’s not dialect. It’s another way to say だと？ in Japanese.

So だ？ means almost same as だと？

Intonation is different from each other.だ？　is like raising the end of the word gradually.

And だ? is interchangeable with だぁ？　だって？　だと？ etc