# Do certain particles behave like nouns? Case in point:「かも」

Tags: particles, parts-of-speech

> これもしかしたら最後のスタック・エクスチェンジの投稿になるかも**な**のです。

> その質問はちょっとムズイかも**だ**から、パスします。

Everywhere I looked「かも」is listed as 助詞. Does this mean some particles behave like nouns? It's also interesting to note that 「かも」comes from「かもしれない」which conjugates like an i-adjective. Off the top of my head I haven't thought of any other similar contractions/particles, but I think there should be more examples.

---

Come to think of it, 「からの」, 「での」...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

だ can follow something other than a noun/na-adjective in standard Japanese:

- [Is 「３人いるだと」 grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5693/5010)
- [~たいだとか why is there a だ here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60014/5010)
- [Is there really any difference between だなんて and なんて?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77933/5010)
- [what does としてもだ mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58949/5010)

That said, your examples are not very "standard". かもなのです smells to me like a role language or キャラ語尾 known as [なのだ口調](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0)/[なのです口調](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99). As a キャラ語尾 in anime/manga, even something like 見ましょうなのです, 見ろです, 見てくださいなのです or 見ろなのだ is not rare. Although a native speaker in the real world may occasionally say ～かもなのです colloquially or half-jokingly, this should be used sparingly and only in very informal settings. ～かもだ/～かもです is relatively more tolerated as 若者言葉 (e.g., (そう)かもですけど = (そう)かもだけど = "that may be true but"), but you have to avoid it in formal sentences.