# Confusing on understanding【知ってるであるか】

Tags: grammar, manga

why there is a verb 「知ってる」plus another[であるか]？
[image]

Answer (score 9):

It's 100% ungrammatical in standard Japanese, but some fictional characters speak like this. This is a [キャラ語尾](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE) that is sometimes referred to as である口調. A typical user of this 語尾 is an eccentric doctor or a dumb and pompous aristocrat, and they often use 吾輩 as a first-person pronoun. In addition to standard usages like 本当である, users of である口調 may speak like this:

- そうであるか (←そうですか)
- おいしいである (←おいしいです)
- 見たである (←見たよ)
- 行くである (←行きましょう・行きなさい)
- おはようである (←おはようございます)

There is also なのだ/なのです口調 (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/85831/5010)).