# what is ございまする?

Tags: keigo, anime

Watching Gintama, ep. 35.  Teenage girl, talking to her date (and also previously, other characters), have used でございまする as a sentence ending "desu" phrase.  Is this an archaic / made up inflection of ござる?  something with ござる + する?

Example:

17:17 ﾎﾝﾄは 怖いんでございまするな｡

17:24 一緒に乗りましょうでございまする！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ございまする (or ござりまする) is an archaic masu-form of ござる.

ござる is an irregular verb whose masu-form is not ござります but ございます. And -まする is one of the old forms of -ます.

> #### [ます](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99/#jn-208067)
>
> [補説]室町時代以降の語で、古くは未然形に「まさ」、**終止・連体形に「まする」**、命令形に「ませい」が用いられることもある。その成立については、「座 (ま) す」「申す」「おはす」を起源とする説があるが、「まゐらす→まらする→まるする→まっする→まっす→ます」と変化したものを本流とみる説が有力である。

Today, this is part of the role language of samurai, and you can commonly hear -まする used in samurai dramas. Real girls in modern Japan never use this unless they are imitating someone.

**EDIT:** 乗りましょうでございまする is an ungrammatical statement in standard Japanese. This type of "unconditional copula or copula-likes (なのだ, なのです, である, です, etc.)" is キャラ語尾 used to characterize fictional characters (mainly in manga and TV programs for children). See: [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/89108/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/85831/5010)

Comment: gotcha, so it's an archaic form of the masu jodoushi and not necessarily connected to gozaru.  as a follow on, isshu ni norimasho <desu> doesn't make a lot of sense to me, are they shoehorning the copula for comedic effect?

Comment: @romnempire Yes you can say 行きまする, 見まする, etc., too. As for your last question, please see the edit.