# How should I understand the grammatical construction たりだとか?

Tags: grammar

> 「ええ。他にも、一緒に班組もうぜ！って言ったらマジのトーンで『えぇ……』って言われ**たりだとか**、落ちた消しゴム拾ってあげたら『あ……それ、もういらないからあげる……』って言われ**たりだとか**……」

Hi. How should I understand the construction たりだとか grammatically and semantically? Is たり a noun so we need だ?
I know the 〜たり…〜たり form used to list multiple examples. とか has the same function, it seems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This だ is a special type of だ that adds a feeling of disdain, doubt, surprise, etc. It can even directly follow the dictionary form of a verb/adjective:

- [~たいだとか why is there a だ here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60014/5010)
- [Is 「３人いるだと」 grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5693/5010)
- [Is there really any difference between だなんて and なんて?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77933/5010)
- [Usage (correctness) of だと after verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15057/5010)

So you can think of だとか as a set expression used to list two or more unfavorable things.

Technically, 「～って言われるだとか、～って言われるだとか」 is enough, but I don't feel たりだとか is wordy or redundant. It's hard to explain why, but たり is used to describe multiple actions while とか here describes multiple reasons, so they may be playing slightly different roles.